# Block undo from changing UIList index

Tags: scripting, interface, grease-pencil

I have this litle problem.

When I change the index of a UIList, and then I execute other action (in this case, painting in a grease pencil layer), if I then undo the stroke I just did, that undo also changes the index I was previously.

I would like the index to remain the same after undoing the stroke. So I was wondering if there was a way to achieve this.

Any idea?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [one of old core issues](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/69760). You can't do much about it

Comment: Is good to know at least, Thank you for the info mate :)